# Why Am I receiving an "autoplot is not supported" Error?

Tags: r

I'm currently trying to create an autoplot for the tsibble table that I have created (using the NikeDataset). I've attached my code below:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(fpp3)
library(tsibble)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggfortify)
rm(list = ls())
file <- '~/Downloads/Nike_QuarterlySales_2010Q1-2020Q1 (1).dat'
Sales_table <- read_csv(file, col_names = c("Time", "Quarter", "Sales"))
Sales_table_ts <- as_tsibble(add_column(Sales_table, qtr =yearquarter("2010 Q1")+ 0:40, .before=TRUE ), index = qtr)
Sales_table_ts <- Sales_table_ts %>%
  mutate(LogSales = log(Sales))

head(Sales_table_ts)
tail(Sales_table_ts)

Sales_table_ts

Sales_table_ts %>%
  autoplot(Sales) +
  geom_point(aes(y=Sales, color=Qtr_factor)) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("black", "blue", "purple", "red")) +
  ggtitle("Quarterly sales for Amazon with color coding") +
  xlab("Time") + ylab("Sales")
```

I'm currently receiving this error : "Error in `autoplot()`:
! Objects of type tbl_ts/tbl_df/tbl/data.frame not supported by autoplot."

What could be a possible solution so I can get this to work?

Comment: Can you successfully run `autoplot(guinea_rice)`? That minimal example should run after successfully loading the `fpp3` package. Any errors on loading your libraries? If not, does `fpp3::autoplot(Sales_table_ts, Sales)` run? (If that fixes it, then the problem might be a conflict where you have multiple packages with an `autoplot()` function, but not all of them work on your data.)